# flutter problem: How to make button with centered text and right side Icon

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I want to make a button, In this button I want a text and icon both but text should be in center and icon will be right side.

this is code of button.

```
  bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
        padding:
            const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, bottom: 20, left: 20, right: 20),
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 45,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _controller.nextPage(
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                curve: Curves.easeIn,
              );
              if(_currentPage + 1 == splashData.length){
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
              }
              
            },
            child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
    
                  "Next",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 50,),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                  child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward,color: whiteColor,),
                )
              ],
            ),

            color: skyBlue,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

I want like this button

[image]

but is becoming like this.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below code, used `Opacity` widget and set `opacity:0`

***Note***: Don't used `FlatButton` its depricated by **Flutter** used instead of `ElevatedButton`, `TextButton`

Refer [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons) to new buttons

```
  ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          //write your onPressed function here
          print('Pressed');
        },
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Opacity(
              opacity: 0,
              child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
            ),
            Text('Next'),
            Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Comment: The explanation here is that you have 3 widgets in your row. The magic is the use of `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween`. This argument puts all unused space in the row width evenly between the 3 widgets. The first widget is a placeholder and is made invisible by `opacity: 0`. You could even use an empty `Container` widget here.

Comment: @RoslanAmir Yes we can use `Container()`, `SizedBox()` Widgets also instead of `Opacity()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use Stack instead of Row to achieve easily.
Inside Stack you can use Positioned(right: 10, child: Icon()) also.

```
      Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: const [
              Text(

                'Next',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward, color: Colors.white,),
            )
            ],
          )
```

We have more than two ways to achieve it. I have given two easiest option to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Expanded` (and play with the `flex` property if needed).
Also add an `Align`

For instance:

```
            Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Expanded(),
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    "Next",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                      child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward,color: whiteColor),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```